# Google chrome search engine with multiple parameters

Tags: google-chrome

I am looking for a way to quickly map words into several params of a url like this:

```
keyword param1 param2 ... paramN : cc eth usd 1
```

that will be mapped into `https://currencio.co/%s/%s/%s/` or `https://currencio.co/%1/%2/%3/` using relative or absolute references respectively.

It's similar to what searchEngines do, but they are limited to only one substitution.

[image]

The query url is: `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%s`

> Is that possible or might there be an extension that does that?